# Ubuntu Touch and Steam

Tags: nvidia, games, steam, client

Is it possible to run the Steam client on Ubuntu Touch? I'm looking to install Ubuntu Touch on my Nvidia Shield, but I'm only going to install it if I'm able to use the Steam client to stream games on it :)

Comment: There's no Steam client for Ubuntu Touch.

Comment: Something like this, it's best to experiment yourself.  I've not heard of anybody doing this; that's not to say it can't be done.  Please let me know how your experience goes if you decide to try this out.